# Querydsl web with contains

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, querydsl

I'm looking for the simplest way (with  least code/customization as possible) to provide a HTTP API to search objects from my database.

So far, I was using querydsl, and a spring controller that simply delegates to the underlying repository:

```
@GetMapping("/folder")
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Folder> getFolders(Predicate p) {
    return repo.findAll(p);
}
```

This works well. For example I can do:

```
http://localhost/api/folder/owner=foo
```

which returns all folders that have the owner `foo`.

However, I can't search fields that *start with* a given keyword. I want to be able to do this:

```
http://localhost/api/folder/name=foo*
```

which should return all folders that start with `foo`. I don't mind if the syntax is different so long as I can search with a 'startsWith' predicate.

I found this library: https://bitbucket.org/gt_tech/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/src/master/ which seems to provide what I need.

It worries me a bit that I need a new dependency, which is not from spring itself. Is it the best solution available ? If so, how to make it work with my project ? I tried adding the maven dependency, but it's not working, do I need to do something else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can override the bindings to use a like expression, something like the below:

```
@Repository
public interface FolderRepository extends JpaRepository<Folder, Long>, 
       QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Folder>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QFolder> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QFolder folder) {
        bindings.bind(folder.owner).first((path, value) -> 
                  path.likeIgnoreCase(value + "%"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However that seems very specific, what if I have 50 fields in my object. Is there no generic way to provide a startsWith ? And I can't provide an equals now, right ?

Comment: I fyou want that kind of fucntionality then use the correct tool for the job, be that the extension you linked to, GraphQL, or something else.

Comment: Or https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-rsql-fiql

Comment: So regarding the tool that I linked, can you please guide me on how to use it ? As I said in my original question, I tried adding it as a dependency, but it's not enough

Comment: Can you please help me further ?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I've been able to get the value operators library to work for strings and numeric but struggling with the java 8 datetime classes.

Comment: @moup Did you figure this out? Im having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom Query DSL binder as [@Alan Hay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356423/alan-hay) noted but override the customize method as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface FolderRepository extends JpaRepository<Folder, Long>, 
       QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Folder>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QFolder> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QFolder folder) {
        bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> 
                  path.startsWith(value));
    }
}
```